# Untrusted packages warning

Tags: 15.04, packaging, gnupg

When I try to update my system I get following warnings:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu.mirror.lhisp.com vivid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu.mirror.lhisp.com vivid-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu.mirror.lhisp.com vivid-proposed Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu.mirror.lhisp.com vivid-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

I tried to add missing keys using :

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys KEY_VALUE
```

I've got the following message,

```
gpg: requesting key C0B21F32 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com 
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed 
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I've tried also this solution :

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

But I still get the above warning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540) describing your situation.

A workaround that can help to fix

navigate to the directory `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` and remove unused keys.

read [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540/comments/1) for more information

Answer (score 0):

This happens, when a mirror server has not been fully updated.

You can try to do it later, or switch to another mirror in

System Settings -> Software & Updates.